# why id change after deleting the row in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I make a simple demo of list .in this demo I am trying to delete row when i click to row .it is working fine ,I am able to delete row when i click on row.
Actually my issue is that I gave **id** to each row like that **$index** .So first row **`id =0`** and second row **`id =1`**.But when click first row (mean id=0) it deleted.Now when I click second row which have **id ="1"** .display **id =0** why ? why my id change .is there any way to delete the rows but id remain same as previous .here is my code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgbpzO

```
var app=angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller('maincntr',function($scope){

    $scope.changeValue={names:[{
        'name':"naveen",
        'lastname':"sharma"

    },{
        'name':"parveen",
        'lastname':"kumar"

    }]};

    $scope.rowClickEvent=function(id){
       alert(id)
        $scope.changeValue.names.splice($scope.changeValue.names.indexOf(id), 1);
    };


});
```

Answer (score 3):

It is happening because when you delete any element from array ng-repeat link it again so you will have again `$index` start from 0.

Suppose I have array [1,2,3] index is now 0,1,2 so ng-repeat shows $index as 0
Now i deleted 1 from it array is now [1,2] so index is again compiled by ng-repeat and again start from 0,1 therefore again 0 comes first .

Hope it help . :)

Comment: @squired is there any other way to give id to rows which never change

Comment: @user944513 why you need id ? if you can send complete object with the help of this or if you need that you can assign id to your object of array.

Comment: thanks understand is there any way to give id link ="id_0" and "id_1"..and after delete it remain same